# When asked to provide recent research examples, how should I chose the right papers?

Tags: publications, authorship, author-order

I was asked to provide two **recent examples of research work** by one hiring committee for a "research scholar" position at a research institute in the field of environmental sciences. I think the employees sometimes supervise for PhD students from a university nearby, so...

...I have several very good first-author papers dating back three years; one first-author from last year (but I think not so strong as the older papers) and a recent paper were a post-doc is the first author and I am second (corresponding author). In between I have papers were I am the fourth or seventh author but these do  not count here.

Should I list:

- the "better" ones, although both older,
- or one older one and the recent one were I am the correspondence author?

What do you think to count for recent research? And what role in the author list should one play when want to show it as an example of my work?

Comment: What type of position are you applying for? If postdoc, your first author work is important. If permanent, it could be better to show works where you had a supervisory role.

Comment: it is not advertised as a post-doc, it is a "scholar" position. not sure what it means exactly.

Comment: Did the documentation actually say they had to be examples of _your own_ research work?  To me, the job title "scholar" suggests that undertaking original research may not be a major component of the job.

Comment: it is a research scholar job, they do research and publish often, so I am sure it has to be _my work_ . Otherwise it does not make sense, who's work should I show instead?

Comment: Thanks, @user3624251.  Now we know the job title also has the word "research" in it, my previous comment is not apposite.

Comment: I think "recency" would also be affected by how old the data are. I have worked on projects where the data were collected 10 years ago and then languished. I'm not sure how we can answer, but your best two papers in the past three years sounds fine, as long as the work itself was similarly recent

Comment: OK @DanielHatton I added the job title also to the main text